# Put select element in a javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a javascript prompt pop up that has a selection element in it rather than a text input. When searching for a solution it seems that using jquery could definitely work but I am new to HTML and javascript and the tutorials for a jquery popup are daunting (I cannot figure out how to implement them)! Is it possible to create such a pop up with just javascript? I was hoping something like this would be possible:

```
prompt(<select>[options...]</select>);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The jQueryUI ones are fairly simple to use; http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form (most code in that example is not just applicable to that demo)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [modal dialog](https://web.archive.org/web/20110719050941/http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html). This is really just a DIV with HTML inside it, with an overlay over the rest of the page.

You can roll-your-own or use a ready-made one from a library.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not possible with prompt; If you want such thing you'll have to fake a dialog box in javascript

Comment: Is it a simple matter to fake the dialog box or would a modal dialog (as suggested by Diodeus) be simpler?

Comment: That's the way to fake it; he means the same thing. I would suggest using jQueryUI as Alex K. sais; it's used alot and easy to learn