# How to create java script prompt with dropdown

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to coding in web technology. To my surprise got to know that we can have prompt only with text. My requirement is to have prompt with options(dropdown) list which when selected will store that selection in some global variable in PHP.

Really don't have idea on how to? Tried jquery etc but no relevant info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8973996/3190165) will help you.

Comment: please try to do something first.

Comment: you need a modal box!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of a standard JavaScript prompt, you can use something like [Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) from [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

See [this demo](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KkHyw) for some idea on how those modals can look like and behave.

This is how you define the modals - example from the Bootstrap page:

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

It results in something like this:

[image]
You can add any HTML inside, including [dropdown menus](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns).